# Reduce Looping Time in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

1. I am running the following program to check the availability of given products (A) in a product catalog (B)

2. The program is working fine within small input of given product and catalog like example below with 3 products in given products and 3 products in catalog.

3. The issue is that when the given products and the product catalog become bigger like 50,000 given products and 150,000 products in catalog, it takes a lot of time and effort to run the program. O

4. Every single product in A will loop through entire catalog B to select the maximum match. So the loop will be 50,000 X 150,000.

5. They are all in Excel. Table A has 2 columns (Seller_Name and product_title) with 50000 rows of product. Table B has 2 columns (product_code and product_title) with 150,000 rows

6. I cut the product tile by white-space like example below to run program.

7. Kindly let me know how to tackle this.

Thank you!

**Input:**

```
def available(product, catalog):
    items = [_ for _ in product if _ != "NaN"]
    if isinstance(catalog[0], str):
        catalog = [catalog]

    max_match = (0, [])
    for catalog in catalog:
        matched_count = 0
        for item in items:
            if item in catalog:
                matched_count += 1
        max_match = max(max_match, (matched_count, catalog)) # tuple score + catalog_item

    return "_".join(items), max_match[1], max_match[0] / len(items) if len(items) != 0 else 0

def availables(products, catalog):
    return [available(product, catalog) for product in products]

A =([['mai', 'dubai', '200ml', 'NaN'],
                ['mai', 'dubai', 'cup'],
                ['mai', 'dubai', '1.5l']]) #multiple products

B =([['natural','mineral','water', 'cups', '200', 'ml', 'pack', 'of', '24', 'mai', 'dubai'],
                ['2-piece', 'glitzi', 'power', 'inox', 'power', 'dish'],
                ['15-piece', 'bones', 'for', 'dog', 'multicolour', 'rich']]) #

output=[]
for res in availables(A, B):
    output.append(res)

import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(output)
df
```

**Output:**

```
    0   1   2
0   mai_dubai_200ml [natural, mineral, water, cups, 200, ml, pack,...   0.666667
1   mai_dubai_cup   [natural, mineral, water, cups, 200, ml, pack,...   0.666667
2   mai_dubai_1.5l  [natural, mineral, water, cups, 200, ml, pack,...   0.666667
```

Comment: It is in tabular data frame actually. Then , I convert them to list

Comment: sure. They are all in Excel. Table A has 2 columns (Seller_Name and product_title) with 50000 rows of product. Table B has 2 columns (product_code and product_title) with 150,000 rows.

Comment: add it to your main post, make it like your output data. 10 rows should do.

Comment: sure, i'll do. thank you

Comment: Are you doing 1 to 1 match of A to B ? 1st row of A to match 1st row of B, then 2nd row of A to match 2nd row of and so on ? If no, how did you get 0.666667 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is different from the 1st post, thus I try to be more flexible as possible for having different inputs.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def available(product, catalog):

    try:
        product.remove('NaN')
    except: 
        pass
    l = len(product)

    r = np.array([len(set(product).intersection(set(c))) for c in catalog])

    max_match = np.max(r)
    max_match_id = np.argmax(r)

    return "_".join(product), catalog[max_match_id], max_match/l

def availables(products, catalog):
    return [available(product, catalog) for product in products]

A =([['mai', 'dubai', '200ml', 'NaN'],
                ['mai', 'dubai', 'cup'],
                ['mai', 'dubai', '1.5l']]) #multiple products

B =([['natural','mineral','water', 'cups', '200', 'ml', 'pack', 'of', '24', 'mai', 'dubai'],
                ['2-piece', 'glitzi', 'power', 'inox', 'power', 'dish'],
                ['15-piece', 'bones', 'for', 'dog', 'multicolour', 'rich']]) #


output=[ res for res in availables(A, B) ]


df=pd.DataFrame(output)
df



 0                                                  1             2   
0  mai_dubai_200ml  [natural, mineral, water, cups, 200, ml, pack,...   0.666667 
1    mai_dubai_cup  [natural, mineral, water, cups, 200, ml, pack,...   0.666667 
2   mai_dubai_1.5l  [natural, mineral, water, cups, 200, ml, pack,...   0.666667
```

Comment: thanks for your input. The objective is to check the availability of A in B. So the output should start from A. Your output starts from B. Kindly have a look again at my output. Thank you.

Comment: Kindly have a look at it again. I believe your program will be faster than mine. Looking forward to hearing from you more. Thank you.

Comment: Wops, used wrong variable in the "join", edited now

Comment: right now, my program is time-consuming. Looking for a better program to deliver the same output even with huge data input.

Comment: Now you have the right output in column 0 and 1. Column 2 is slightly different since I filled A lists with 'NaN', therefore they are always matching last element (or as you called it, item). You can edit that as it better suits your goal

Comment: Thanks. Give me some time. I need to check your program with my entire data. I need you tonight. Don't leave me :). You save me actually. I am running my current program from the afternoon and it is still running. No output.

Comment: There is an error: AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'mean' when running on another input. Kindly have a look at my input again. I updated it. Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output with the new input? Structure looks completely different. Also not sure when you have a single bool object, you should always have an array of booleans to apply numpy mean

Comment: My current program is working fine on the updated input.

Comment: I am sorry for that inconvenience.

Comment: This edit is flexible, yet we lose speed since cannot use numpy vectorization. Please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Code analysis:

A, B's length is 50000.

Calls availables(A, B)

```
def availables(products, catalog):
    return [available(product, catalog) for product in products]
```

Calls available(product, [int * 50000]) 50000 times

```
for catalog in catalog: <---- btw what is this ANYWAYS that's 50000 calls
        matched_count = 0
        for item in items: <---- Another 4 calls?
            if item in catalog:
                matched_count += 1
        max_match = max(max_match, (matched_count, catalog))
```

So you see your for loop will run a grand total of 50000x50000x4=10 billion times

Sorry but that will not run in less than a second, or even any reasonable seconds.